# Is the Taylor series a generalized Fourier series?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, orthogonal-polynomials

Let $V$ be the vector space of functions that are smooth $0$: they have derivatives of all orders.  Every $f\in V$ can be (locally) expanded into a Taylor series, as $$f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+\frac{f''(0)}{2}x^2+\dots$$

At the same time, suppose $H$ is a (separable) Hilbert space whose intersection with $V$ is dense in the latter, and, moreover, that in fact $f\in H$ too.  Pick any orthonormal basis $\{e_j\}_{j\in J}$.  Then $f$ has a generalized Fourier expansion $$f=\sum_{j\in J}{\langle e_j,f\rangle e_j}$$  <sup>(For which argument is antilinear, I follow the physicist's convention.)</sup>

There are many Hilbert spaces with a polynomial orthonormal basis; Wikipedia has a [whole article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_polynomials) about them.  Write $$e_j(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{c_{j,n}x^n}$$ where only finitely-many coefficients are nonzero.

Ideally, the generalized Fourier expansion above will converge rearrangeably.  We can then "collect terms" into a series $$f(x)=\sum_{j\in J}{\langle e_j,f\rangle c_{j,0}}+\left(\sum_{j\in J}{\langle e_j,f\rangle c_{j,1}}\right)x+\left(\sum_{j\in J}{\langle e_j,f\rangle c_{j,2}}\right)x^2+\dots$$  Does there exist a Hilbert space for which we can recover Taylor's formula: $$\sum_{j\in J}{c_{j,n}\langle e_j,f\rangle}=\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}\text{?}$$

<sup>(Based on [a recent deleted question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4518488/equivalence-of-derivative-operator-and-inner-product-with-polynomials).)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Yes, or no, or also yes.  It all depends on whether your functions are of a real or complex variable, and how wildly you can imagine a Hilbert space.  But before I begin, a spot of notation: let $p_n(x)=x^n$.

#### The complex-variable case

Functions smooth at $0$ are necessarily analytic on a neighborhood thereof.  Suppose that said neighborhood is large enough to contain the closed unit disk $\mathbb{D}$; then we can compute that our inner product explicitly.

Since $$f=\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}p_n}$$ we must have $\langle p_n,f\rangle=\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$.  Now write $g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty{a_nx^n}$.  Then, by Cauchy's formula, \begin{align*}
\langle g,f\rangle&=\left\langle\sum_{n=0}^\infty{a_np_n},f\right\rangle \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{\overline{a_n}f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}} \\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\oint_{\partial\mathbb{D}}{\frac{\overline{a_n}}{z^{n+1}}f(z)\,dz}} \\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\partial\mathbb{D}}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{\overline{a_nz^n}}{z}f(z)}\,dz} \\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\partial\mathbb{D}}{\overline{g(z)}f(z)\,\frac{dz}{z}}
\end{align*} since $\overline{z}z=1$ on the contour.

Conversely, one can begin with that inner product directly: it is straightforward to verify that it is an inner product (taking the complex conjugate of the differential is the same as changing variables to $z^{-1}$…or just traversing the contour in the opposite direction).  But then $$\langle p_n,f\rangle=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\partial\mathbb{D}}{\overline{z}^nf(z)\,\frac{dz}{z}}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\partial\mathbb{D}}{\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}\,dz}=\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$$ again by Cauchy's formula.

Lastly, the technical details: does this inner product make the space of "analytic functions on $\mathbb{D}$" Hilbert?  Yes, because we can compute the value at any point on the interior from the boundary via Cauchy's theorem and a Möbius transform.  Thus convergence in $L^2$ on the boundary implies in fact uniform convergence on the interior.  And is that Hilbert space dense in $V$?  Yes, because it contains all polynomials.

#### The real-variable case

Ideally, $$\langle p_n,p_m\rangle=\delta_{n,m}$$ where $\delta$ is Kronecker's delta; as much holds in the complex-variable case.  But one cannot hope for so simple a result, for then $$1=\langle p_m,p_m\rangle=\langle p_{2m},p_0\rangle=0$$ for any nonzero $m$.

Worse, the existence of bump functions inhibits any relaxation to other families of orthogonal polynomials.  To be precise, given any open set $U$ disjoint from $0$, there exists a bump function $\phi$ supported on $U$.  Adding $\phi$ to $f$ changes the values of $f$ on $U$, but does not modify $f$'s Taylor series away from $U$.

Formally, the "Maclaurin series map" $M$, which sends each function in $V$ to its corresponding Maclaurin series, factors through the stalk at the origin: the quotient vector space $\mathcal{G}$ in which we identify elements of $V$ that coincide on any neighborhood of $0$.  (I have chosen the letter $\mathcal{G}$, because elements of that vector space are often called "[germs of functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germ_(mathematics)).")

But expansion in a generalized Fourier series is an isometric map.  Rearrangement is not isometric, but it is bijective, because a rearranged series can always be "unrearranged."  Identifying along the composite bijection, $H$ must intersect $\mathcal{G}$ densely in both vector spaces.

Thus we have no hope of writing an inner product on $H$ that is "just" an integral; any measure for such an integral would be supported at precisely $\{0\}$.  Indeed, let $\delta_0^{(n)}:\mathcal{G}\to\mathbb{R}$; $$\delta_0^{(n)}(f)=f^{(n)}(0)$$  Then the span of $\{\delta_0^{(n)}\}_n$ is dense in $\mathcal{G}^*$.  Any inner product must be built out of derivatives at $0$ alone.

Much like the complex case, figuring out the inner product is now just an computation: represent each element of $\mathcal{G}$ by the sequence of derivatives at $0$; thus \begin{gather*}
f=(f(0),f'(0),f''(0),\dots) \\
p_0=(1,0,0,\dots) \\
p_1=(0,1,0,\dots) \\
p_2=(0,0,2,\dots) \\
p_n=(\dots,0,n!,\dots)
\end{gather*} where the $n!$ appears in the $n$<sup>th</sup> coordinate (with zero-based indexing).  We seek a bilinear form on these infinite sequences such that $$\langle p_n,f\rangle=\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}\text{;}$$ it is immediate that $$\langle f,g\rangle=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{f^{(n)}(0)g^{(n)}(0)}{n!^2}}$$ will do the job.